# How to disable the back browser button after a user logs into a profile

Tags: django, authentication, validation

I am trying to make a user not be able to go back to the login page from a profile page after logging in
I have tried using `@never_cache` but it still seems to be saving the session and I can go back with the browser back button without logging out.

I have then implemented the`@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)` and its did not work.

I then tried adding a `random_string` and `timestamp` after the login url but this made the profile page unreachable

Here is my current user_login view:

```
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True) #Ensure you cant go back to login with the browser back button
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully')  # Display success message
            login(request, user)
            timestamp_query_param = int(timezone.now().timestamp())
            return redirect(f'profile/?t={timestamp_query_param}')
        # Handling authentication failure
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Account does not exist or password is wrong')  # Display error message and redirect the same page
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: How about writing if statement in the `user_login` view like this: `if not request.user.is_authenticated`?

Comment: When I use that, the error upon wrong details is not appearing. Its giving ``AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'`` error